# Kotlin iterator to check if payload list have an id/projectId or not, returning false when there is no attributes?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I have an issue where i have a method where i am checking the payload has the attributes or not. When i am sending my payload i want to check that the user dont have inserted attributes which not allowed in the payload.

My entity class:

```
@Entity
data class ProjectAssociated(

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    var id: UUID? = null,

    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    var projectId: UUID? = null,

    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    var associatedProjectId: UUID? = null
)
```

My Service class:

```
fun addAssociatedProjectByProjectId(
    projectId: UUID, 
    projectAssociatedList: MutableList<ProjectAssociated>
): MutableList<ProjectAssociated> {

    if (projectAssociatedList.isNotEmpty()) {

        println(projectAssociatedList)

        if (!projectAssociatedList.map { it.id }.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            val errorMessage = "Not allowed to provide parameter 'id' in this request"
            throw UserInputValidationException(errorMessage)
        }

        if (!projectAssociatedList.map { it.projectId }.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            val errorMessage = "Not allowed to provide parameter 'projectId' in this request"
            throw UserInputValidationException(errorMessage)
        }

        val checkIds = projectAssociatedList.map { 
            projectRepository.existsById(it.associatedProjectId) 
        }

        if (checkIds.contains(false)) {
            val errorMessage = "One or more ID 'associatedProjectId' not exists"
            throw UserInputValidationException(errorMessage)
        }
    }

    return projectAssociatedList.map {
        projectAssociatedRepository.save(
            ProjectAssociated(
                null,
                projectId,
                it.associatedProjectId
            )
        )
    }.toMutableList()
}
```

My Controller class:

```
@ApiOperation("Add associated Projects to a specific Project")
@PostMapping(path = ["/project-associated"], consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
fun createAssociatedProjectList(
    @ApiParam("The id of the Project", required = true)
    @RequestParam("id")
    id: UUID,
    @ApiParam("JSON object representing the ProjectAssociated")
    @RequestBody projectAssociated: MutableList<ProjectAssociated>
): ResponseEntity<WrappedResponse<MutableList<ProjectAssociated>>> {

    val createdProjectAssociatedList = projectService.addAssociatedProjectByProjectId(id, projectAssociated)

    return ResponseEntity
        .status(201)
        .location(URI.create("$id/project-associated"))
        .body(
            ResponseDto(
                code = 201,
                data = PageDto(list = mutableListOf(createdProjectAssociatedList))
            ).validated()
        )
}
```

But when i try to send this payload with the project id in @RequestParam:

```
[
  {
    "associatedProjectId": "7fe40f90-5178-11ea-9136-1b65a920a5d9"
  },
  {
    "associatedProjectId": "7fe8aaaa-5178-11ea-9136-1b65a920a5d9"
  }
]
```

I have a custom exception where i tell the user if `projectId` or the `id` is in the payload that is now allowed to have it in the payload. When i try to POST the payload example above it tells me that `projectId` or `id` is in the request? How can that be?

I also printed out the list before if checks:

`[ProjectAssociated(id=null, projectId=null, associatedProjectId=7fe40f90-5178-11ea-9136-1b65a920a5d9), ProjectAssociated(id=null, projectId=null, associatedProjectId=7fe8aaaa-5178-11ea-9136-1b65a920a5d9)]`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the block `projectAssociatedList.map { it.id }` you are mapping your list to something like `[null, null]` and it is not `null` or `empty`.

So, the complete condition `!projectAssociatedList.map { it.id }.isNullOrEmpty()` returns `true`.

If you want to continue using the same logic, you should use `!projectAssociatedList.mapNotNull { it.id }.isNullOrEmpty()` instead.

The `mapNotNull` function will filter the null values and output a list just with the not null values. If there is only `null` values, the list will be empty.

But, a simpler and expressive way to check if there is any not null attribute in a list of objects could be `projectAssociatedList.any { it.id != null }`

Comment: `projectAssociatedList.any { it.id != null }` this one works, but why do i need to have `.any` ? Why does it not work with `.map` ?

Comment: `any` is a function that returns `true` if any of the values in the list satisfies the predicate, in this case, the predicate is `it.id != null`. So, if any element of the list has an `id` different of `null`, the function returns `true` and get into the `if` block.

Comment: With the `map` function it doesn't work because the return is a list of nulls like `[null, null]` and a list of null is different of a null list nor an empty list. This way, the function `isNullOrEmpty` returns false and, as you were denying it with `!` it was becoming a `true` result and entering the if block.